# Give Dojo TabContainer an ID

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following code in my page that creates a new Dojo/Dijit TabContainer.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.ComboButton" iconClass="dijitIconEdit">
    <span>
    Blank
    </span>
    <div dojoType="dijit.Menu">
    <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" iconClass="dijitIconEdit">
        Letter to Client
        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">
            newLetterToClientPane = dojox.layout.ContentPane({ title:'New Letter to Client', href:'some_url', closable:true })
            dijit.byId('mainTabs').addChild(newLetterToClientPane)
        </script>
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" iconClass="dijitIconEdit">
        Letter to Company
        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">
            newLetterToCompanyPane = dojox.layout.ContentPane({ title:'New Letter to Company', href:'some_url', closable:true })
            dijit.byId('mainTabs').addChild(newLetterToCompanyPane)
        </script>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This all works fine. I just wonder how I would give the new TabContainer an ID since I need to re-populate later in the script but I can't do this with out and ID. I'm only asking because the Dojo page on [dojox.layout.ContentPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/layout/ContentPane.html) and [dijit.layout.ContentPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html) makes no mention of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
newLetterToClientPane = dojox.layout.ContentPane({ id: "cp1", title:'New Letter to Client', href:'some_url', closable:true });
```

You can then later access that widget by

```
dijit.byId("cp1")
```

for example

```
dijit.byId("cp1").attr ("title", "new title");
```

Note that jsid will create a global JS variable with the id you specify - so be careful if you do not want to add to the global memory
It does offer convenience though in that you dont need to do dijit.byId to access it
you could do:

```
cp1.attr("title", "new title");
```

if you use jsId as cp1

Aso note the difference between dojo.byId and dijit.byId:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/info.html

Since id behavior is same across all widgets, I am guessing they added the details in the base dijit doc available at the link above

Answer (score 1):

use `jsId` as

```
<div jsId='myfirstTab' dojoType="dijit.form.ComboButton" iconClass="dijitIconEdit">
```

**UPDATE**

assign yourself the new Id

```
newLetterToClientPane = dojox.layout.ContentPane({ title:'New Letter to Client', href:'some_url', closable:true, jsId :'myfirstTab' })
```

Comment: I need the ID for the new `dojox.layout.ContentPane` that I am attaching to `mainTabs`

Comment: I just updated my answer, why dont you set yourself his id, and to have a different id each time just use a counter as jsId :'myfirstTab' + nb

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but the tabs I create are static not dynamic so I can just hardcode the IDs

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by passing the `id` as the second argument to the constructor

Much like a standard way.

```
newLetterToClientPane = dojox.layout.ContentPane({ title:'New Letter to Client', href:'some_url', closable:true }, "cpId")
```

Comment: I thought that was if you wanted to target a `<div>` to be populated by the `ContentPane`